# Accessing BPF maps from kernel space

Tags: linux, kernel, ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I am beginning with XDP and BPF maps.

I understand that to access a BPF map from userspace, we use `bpf_*` syscalls. For example, `bpf_map_lookup_elem()` is used to lookup an element of a BPF map in the userspace program. However, I noticed that the same syscalls are also used to access maps in the XDP programs loaded on the kernel (ref. [here](https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/blob/master/advanced03-AF_XDP/af_xdp_kern.c#L27)).

I assumed such programs should be running in the kernel space, and hence is there some other way these BPF maps should be accessed from the kernel space? Or is the XDP loaded program also part of the userspace but only running within the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To lookup map elements from userspace, you should use [the `bpf(2)` syscall](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html), with command `BPF_MAP_LOOKUP_ELEM`. The main userspace library for BPF does expose this syscall command as [`bpf_map_lookup_elem()`](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/22411acc4b2c846868fd570b2d9f3b016d2af2cb/docs/libbpf_naming_convention.rst#system-call-wrappers).

To lookup map elements from BPF programs, you indeed need to use the `bpf_map_lookup_elem` BPF helper. In a nutshell, BPF helpers are kernel functions you can call from the BPF bytecode with instruction `call`.

**Despite having the same name, they are however different things: the first is a library function, while the second is a BPF helper.**

Comment: Got it. Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice to know it helped! You can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left. That should help with referencing.